# How do I declare a data source for GlassFish?

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

I know how I'd do this using JBoss: create a `*-ds.xml` file, and drop it into my `deploy` directory.

- Is there a declarative way to do the same with GlassFish (v3.1)?
- Am I thinking about this the wrong way? (See next question)
- Is there a more-Glassfishy way to get my Java EE application to talk to a database?

Other potentially-revelant info:

- I want to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database
- I'm using Eclipse + GlassFish Server Tools
- I know next to nothing about GlassFish. I'm much more familiar with JBoss

Comment: Are you looking to avoid the admin console?

Comment: @bosmacs: yes, unless that's a horrible idea. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just drop a file somewhere (inside of my EAR is fine).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define it in `application.xml` or `ejb-jar.xml` of your EAR. You can even use annotations.

Long answer short: [DataSource Resource Definition in Java EE 6](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/datasource_resource_definition_in_java).

Answer (score 6):

BalusC [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168613/how-do-i-declare-a-data-source-for-glassfish/4169425#4169425) (+1), with Java EE 6 you can declare [datasource definitions](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/datasource_resource_definition_in_java) either through annotations or through the use of deployment descriptors in a standard and portable way.

Just in case you'd be also interested by creating *other* resources than datasources like JMS resources, you can also package a `glassfish-resources.xml` file as part of your application. See:

- [Supporting glassfish-resources.xml](http://blogs.oracle.com/vkraemer/entry/supporting_glassfish_resources_xml)
- [4.1.3 Application scoped resources](http://wikis.sun.com/display/GlassFish/Gfv31ConnectorsJDBC#Gfv31ConnectorsJDBC-4.1.3Applicationscopedresources)